# How to populate a newly opened grid view on click of an item in ListView

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I want to populate grid view that is opened in new activity on click of an item in list view. How to implement? Working on android app development

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
private List<cars> myCars=new ArrayList<cars>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    populateCarsList();
    populateListView();
    registerClickCallback();
}





private void populateCarsList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myCars.add(new cars("Ford",1950,0,"Aman"));
    myCars.add(new cars("Honda",1951,0,"Akhil"));
    myCars.add(new cars("Fiat",1952,0,"Anil"));
    myCars.add(new cars("Mahindra",1953,0,"Ankit"));
    myCars.add(new cars("Maruti",1954,0,"Venu"));
    myCars.add(new cars("Hyundai",1955,0,"Neeta"));
    myCars.add(new cars("Toyota",1956,0,"Naresh"));
    myCars.add(new cars("BMW",1957,0,"Amit"));
    myCars.add(new cars("Merc",1958,0,"Arjun"));
    myCars.add(new cars("Jaguar",1959,0,"Akshit"));
}



private void populateListView() {

ArrayAdapter<cars> adapter=new  AmanListAdapter();
ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.carsListView);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

}


private void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.carsListView);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,int position, long id) 
        {
            cars clickedCar=myCars.get(position);
            String message="You clicked position "+position+" which is "+clickedCar.getMake();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if(position==0)
            {


                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GridView1Activity.class));




        }
            else
            {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,GridView2Activity.class));
            }

        }
    });

}


private class AmanListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<cars>
{
    public AmanListAdapter(){
        super(MainActivity.this,R.layout.item_view,myCars);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View itemView=convertView;
        if(itemView==null)
            itemView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view,parent,false);


        //Find the car to work with
        cars currentCar=myCars.get(position);

        //Fill the view
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_Icon);
        imageView.setImageResource(currentCar.geticonID());

        //Make
        TextView makeText=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtMake);
        makeText.setText(currentCar.getMake());

        //Year
        TextView yearText=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtYear);
        yearText.setText(""+currentCar.getYear());

        //Condition
        TextView conditionText=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_txtCondition);
        conditionText.setText(currentCar.getCondition());


        return itemView;
    }




}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;`enter code here`
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you've asked a relatively broad question which means the reader can't tell if (a) you are new to Android and are asking a basic question that is covered the many tutorials online or (b) incomplete description of the problem which you could improve my showing us what you've tried/read/researched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set clickListener on item of the listView.
2. Create new activity and pass id (using intent) to the new activity.
3. Populate the new activity using the id.

You can use custom adapter.

If you are new to Android, first follow some basic tutorial.

Comment: How to Populate the new activity using Id ?

Comment: You should ask a separate question instead of using the comments.
That way your question will be visible to more people.